# How can I completely avoid webdriver-manager?

Tags: protractor, webdriver-manager

I'm trying to use protractor for e2e tests in my Angular project. I previously installed selenium server and chromedriver in my path and it works fine for non-angular projects. I do not have access to googleapis or any of the alternate cdns required by webdriver-manager.

How can I run protractor tests w/o involving webdriver-manager in any way? I want to use the tools I have installed globally. Is this a possibility?

When I try to run the `ng e2e` I get the error: `Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.`

When I try to run `webdriver-manager update` I get an http 403.

In my `protractor.conf.js` file I have directConnect: true and capabilities.browserName: 'chrome'

I was hoping that by using directConnect it would just find the chromedriver in my path but that isn't the case. In the past I would use the selenium-webdriver npm module to spin-up an instance of chrome driver.

Comment: directConnect works with binaries downloaded locally to your project. If you want to not use it, the logs from webdriver-manager tell you where to download it and how to run the java command. I have fixes coming for Protractor and webdriver-manager in January.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download latest selenium standalone server and chromedriver from https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Create a batch file

```
java -Dselenium.LOGGER.level=WARNING -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:/Program Files (x86)/Selenium/WebDrivers/ChromeDrivers/2.38/chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -port 4444
```

specify the port,Chromedriver location and log level.

Just run the batch file and now you have selenium server running.

In your config file mention Selenium address `127.0.0.1:4444` or `localhost`

Comment: All of these answers are great. In my situation (archaic work environment) this is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ng cli option: `webdriver-update` to make it not to execute webdriver update as following:

`ng e2e --webdriver-update=false`

But `ng e2e` uses the webdriver in local package not global package, I think you need a npm script to copy your pre-prepared webdriver to project local package before execute `ng e2e  --webdriver-update=false`

Answer (score 1):

I think best way is either go for selenium grid([Dockerized Selenium](https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/) or [Jar based grid](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) . Other option is

```
directConnect: true
```

in your protractor config file.

Comment: I wish docker was an option but my org doesn't allow me to use it.