# webdriver-manager update fails with Type error: Cannot read property 'url' of null

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Since two days my protractor tests stopped running because the webdriver-manager update command fails with the following error.
[image]

**EDIT**
The problem is in `...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\dist\lib\provider\chromedriver.js` file.

In `async updateBinary(version)`, on line 59, `const versionObj = version_list_1.getVersion(versionList, osHelper(this.osType, this.osArch), formatVersion(version));` is null.

Comment: Try purging the node modules and installing everything from start.

Comment: @demouser123 Your suggestion was the only thing that worked. Had to nuke it all...

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `webdriver-manager update` the respective drivers are downloaded from a location.

[image]

When it does not know from where to download you will face this issue. You can see in the above image each driver is downloaded a specific URL.

Try uninstalling protractor and install it back again.Then try to run `webdriver-manager update`

Comment: I have done that, and still the same error. I will try to nuke everything and do it all from scratch. Still strange how this happened all of the sudden, after few years of running every night with no problems.

Comment: Also, we have about 50 tests with about 250 specs in total. And from about 4 months, after a chrome update, they started freezing randomly. sometimes after 10 specs, sometimes after 100 specs. all that followed was failing. Downgrading chrome and installing an older version of webdriver-manager solved the issue. And now this...

Comment: Use this solution to avoid webdriver-manager completely. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53358685/8903949

Comment: This package is also really useful. https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone . Install this package globally . then run "selenium-standalone install" to update to latest and "selenium-standalone start" to start the server

Comment: Both the alternatives worked well for me. Hope it helps for you also.