# Protractor Not Running because of Firewall?

Tags: angularjs, angular, protractor

I'm trying to get Protractor working on Windows Server 2016. Using the tutorial on official protractor website, I've got it working on my laptop at home running Windows 10 and a work VM running Windows 7. I have local admin rights on all three. The work VM running Server 2016 just fails with error below when I run the conf.js

```
[16:36:25] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:36:25] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[16:36:45] E/launcher - Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'APC', ip: 'x.x.x.x', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[16:36:45] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'APC', ip: 'x.x.x.x', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:761:15)
    at createDriver (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:626:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
    at C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
[16:36:45] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

The Server 2016 machine is an Azure Cloud VM. The Win7 machine is on-prem. Is this error any indication of a Firewall setting or something being blocked? I've been playing around with this for a few days and can't seem to figure it out. I know my company are all moving to Windows 10 eventually but my server would stay Server 2016 and we'd like to be able to make use of protractor for e2e testing of AngularJS and Angular 2+ apps.

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53358685/8903949

Comment: @BharathKumarS same issue even with that suggestion. Also I have a newer version of selenium webdriver jar than in the referenced post.

Comment: can you please post your protractor config file