# Unable to start selenium server behind proxy to trigger protractor test cases?

Tags: protractor

I have executed the command

```
webdriver-manager start --proxy= proxy value
```

but it throws below error and I am unable to execute my test cases.

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:64:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
}
[15:31:40] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Users\212788560\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.26.0.exe -jar C:\Users\212788560\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444
[15:31:40] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 41800
15:31:41.696 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
15:31:41.883 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2020-01-31 15:31:42.081:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1081ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
15:31:42.806 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
15:31:48.783 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
```

Comment: Looks like a misconfigured DNS setting in your proxy server. What happens if you change `chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com` to `172.217.17.80` (which it resolves to on my machine)?

Comment: Please refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/53358685/8903949