# Error: Could not find update-config.json when running Protractor end to end tests

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor

I have an Angular 6 project and trying to run end-to-end protractor tests.
I keep getting this error during the step:

```
webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false
```

So I installed the webdriver-manager globally and the webdriver-manager folder is in the folder:
C:\Users...\Roaming\npm\node_modules

I then update the webdriver-manager using this command from the folder C:/User/:

```
webdriver-manager update
```

That successfully adds the selenium jar, chromedriver, and geckodriver.

I try running the end to end tests using yarn.
When the script gets to this command:

```
webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false
```

I get this error:
[image]

The update-config.json is in the folder:
[image]

Where is this json file suppose to be and how do I get it there?

**UPDATE**
These are the current scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config local.proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build --output-path ../resources/static",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test-local": "ng test --karmaConfig=karma-local.conf.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "wd:update": "npm run e2e-update && protractor ./e2e/protractor-local.conf.js",
    "wd:start": "webdriver-manager start && protractor ./e2e/protractor-local.conf.js",
    "e2e-local": "npm run e2e-update && protractor ./e2e/protractor-local.conf.js",
    "e2e-local-debugger": "npm run e2e-update && node --inspect-brk node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor ./e2e/protractor-local.conf.js",
    "e2e": "npm run e2e-update && npm run e2e-test",
    "e2e-test": "protractor ./e2e/protractor.conf.js",
    "e2e-update": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e-jenkins-staging": "npm run e2e-update && npm run e2e-staging",
    "e2e-jenkins-prod": "npm run e2e-update && npm run e2e-prod",
    "e2e-staging": "protractor ./e2e/protractor-staging.conf.js",
    "e2e-prod": "protractor ./e2e/protractor-prod.conf.js",
    "sonar": "sonar-scanner"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of local and global installation of webdriver-manager.

Create a npm script in package.json for updating webdriver manager some thing like

```
"wd:update": "webdriver-manager update"
```

This will download the driver and binaries for the webdriver-manager inside your node_modules of the project.

Run this npm script from the project directory npm run `wd:update`

Comment: I would need to do the same with the webdriver-manager install command too, correct?  So the **npm install webdriver-manager** needs to be run from the project folder?

Comment: Nope webdriver-manager comes default with protractor it is a peer dependency. Just update it once and everything will be fine

Comment: I still get the same error. **Cannot find update-config.json**.  The file is in the folder: **webdriver-manager/selenium**
BTW...I called the command **webdriver-manager update** from the root directory folder. I put files in the node_modules folder
What folder should the update-config.json file be?

Comment: Calling the command directly from the root directory is still going to update the global copy of protractor. You need to add a script to your package.json and run that instead. That will actually update the copy of protractor that is local to your project. Should fix your issue.

Comment: Please add a script tag then it will not target the global installation location.

Comment: Added the script and ran **npm run wd:update**.  It displayed that it was using the local install.  Updated selenium, chromedriver, and geckodriver.  Then ran our command to run the e2e tests. (yarn e2e-local).  This calls **webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false**.  Then get the same error...can't find update-config.json

Comment: I think your e2e test command again tries to update webdriver-manager. Just add another script to start webdriver-manager. Then just run your test

Comment: the script command to run the tests is, ** webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false && protractor ./e2e/protractor.conf.js**.  There is no **webdriver-manager start** command.  When I replace the update command with the start command,  The Selenium Server starts but the tests do not run

Comment: Yes just remove the the cmd before && in your test script cmd.

Comment: Only protractor ./e2e/protractor.conf.js is enough

Comment: When I do that, I get the error:
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js:5:15)
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

Comment: Please add your entire npm scripts in the question

Comment: Scripts have been added above

Comment: "e2e-local": "protractor ./e2e/protractor-local.conf.js",. Change e2e local to the above mentioned cmd

Comment: Back to the same error:
Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.

Comment: Ok now go to the .bin folder inside node_modules and run webdriver-manager update in the .bin folder. Issue will be fixed. Then run the test

Comment: went to the .bin folder and ran update using this command:
>webdriver-manager update
That was successfully
Then ran e2e-local command like this:
>yarn e2e-local
got the same error
moved to the webapp folder to folders up (which is where this command works for the rest of the team and got the same error (Error message: Could not find update-config.json.)

Comment: Try uninstalling protractor and install it or try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53358685/8903949

Comment: I checked for the version of protractor installed and it is not installed! (fyi...im an idiot!) So should I install protractor globally or locally

Comment: locally should be fine

Comment: installing protractor globally because there are multiple applications I will need it and it is taking forever

Comment: seems to be stuck on  es6-promise@4.2.8 checking installable status ...how long should this take?

Comment: Had to uninstall webdriver-manager and node. then reinstall them. Then I could install protractor.  working now